# How can i change my v-list background color?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't figure out why my v-list won't update the color whatever i do.

here is my code

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer  app>
      <div style="background-color: grey;" class="d-flex justify-center pa-4 ">
        Fichiers chargés
      </div>


      <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
        <v-btn prepend-icon="mdi-folder" class="mt-4 mb-2 mx-auto text-black bg-green hidden-sm-and-down"
          plain>Parcourir
          ..</v-btn>
        <v-checkbox class="mx-auto" label="Ajout auto. en base"></v-checkbox>
      </div>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-list class="my-list" color="primary"  >
        <v-list-tile v-for=" f in fichiers">
          
            <v-card-text class=" mx-5 px-5 bg-red">
              {{ f.nom }}
            </v-card-text>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-list-item style="width: 0100%;">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            {{ fichiers.length }} Fichiers Chargés
          </div>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>

    </v-navigation-drawer>

  </v-app>
</template>

<style>
  .my-list {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>


<script setup>
let fichiers = [
  {
    nom: "Fichier1",
    taille: "2ko",
    contenu: "jhbjm",
    etat: [],
  }
]

</script>
```

in my devtools i can see that the v-list took the bg-transparent. I tried everything to force it but nothing happened

sorry for my bad english XD

Comment: Could you please provide an online reproduction (or a running snippet here) so we can at least see and debug the style?

Comment: i update the code i hope it's ok

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution :**

Don't forget to give a feedback.

- Use **"!important"** in your "background-color" value

```css
.my-list {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

- Use the **"id"** selector if you don't want to use "!important"

```css
#the-list {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<v-list id="the-list" color="primary"  >
  <v-list-tile v-for=" f in fichiers">
    ...
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

**The reason of your problem :**
If you look at the browser developer tool, you'll find that the class "v-list" is written before your custom class "my-list". That means, the priority is not for your custom class.